C# member to check property for null and set it with async function if needed?
This is NOT a failure of anything. I'm just trying to determine how to write c# more elegantly.
In a C# project I find I am doing an awful lot of
if (null != classX.user || await classX.getUserAsync())
{
     // getUserAsync() either sets classX.user appropriately and returns true, or else returns false.
     // Calls to classX members and other functions that are only OK when classX.user is valid follow

and I'd like to bundle this into a member function like
private async Task<bool> IsUserSet()
{
     if (null != user)
         return await Task.FromResult<bool>(user);
     
     return await getUserAsync();
}

because (IMHO) replacing the if statement with  if (IsUserSet()) is more readable.
However, I'm wondering if the performance hit (there is one with inserting another Task isn't there?) is worth it, or if there is a way to do this without inserting another task. (Or maybe I just need some education on how to write cleaner ASP.NET code!)
*** FINAL Edit after learning a lot from all the comments:

I should consider a ValueTask for any intermediate Task functions
(or when appropriate), it can reduce overhead (thanks Charlieface).
By using ValueTask in    SetUserAsync (was GetUserAsync), I can
incorporate the "null" check inside the SetUserAsync function
instead of creating an intermediate function (Akash, Pedro).
Generally, I shouldn't need to return Task.FromResult<> (I don't
know where I picked up that habit) it adds unnecessary overhead (phuzi).


if (classX.user ?? await classX.getUserAsync()) won't work because classX.user would have to be of type bool? and I'd put money on it being a different type.

Why not just always call await classX.getUserAsync()? Is it not smart enough to check classX.user first?

getUserAsync() name should change to setUserAsync() and user is null condition should be under setUserAsync(). so you have to only check if(classX.user is not null)

phuzi-- thanks, removed my bad coding with classX.user
Heretic Monkey-- You are correct but I'm still wondering about the performance question, is there much of a performance hit in calling that async Task function and having it check for null itself, or is it better to check for null before calling getUserAsync and creating its associated task?

@GregL. performance will be same whether you check before or inside getUserAsync()

Thanks Akash... I was thinking that because of threads like https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/18gjudv/resharper_suggests_replace_async_code_with/ I should avoid unnecessary calls to async functions by checking for null before the call... it's not such a big deal, then?

What sort of code does typically go into the else branch of that if? Is it some common error handling? As in what happens if I don't have a user and can't resolve it?

It's not an error, but that code treats the user as an anonymous (unauthenticated/unknown) user.

A ValueTask will avoid the perf hit if user is alrady retrieved.

Charlieface- Nice, I didn't know about ValueTask, I'm starting to read up about it, sounds like I should incorporate the null check into SetUserAsync() and use ValueTask.

If "user is not null", why do you still need an async call to retrieve the "user that is there"? It almost implies a race condition: user may disappear.

I think you were nearly there with
private async Task<bool> IsUserSet()
{
     if (null != user)
         return await Task.FromResult<bool>(user);
     
     return await getUserAsync();
}

but return await Task.FromResult<bool>(user); would need to be return true;
You could simplify this and do something similar to your original code.
private async Task<bool> IsUserSet()
{
     return user is not null || await getUserAsync();
}

Sidenote on await Task.FromResult()
When you do await Task.FromResult<bool>(user) you have redundant code.
Task.FromResult<bool>(user) wraps user in a completed task and prefixing it with await automatically unwraps it, so await Task.FromResult<bool>(user) can be reduced to user as you weren't actually returning Task<bool> but bool all along and marking a method as async automatically wraps the returned value in a task`

Thanks... I am confused about when to use Task.FromResult vs just the ultimate value, I thought it was best to return with FromResult for functions declared with Task?

@GregL. I've added a bit about await Task.FromResult() to my answer.

Thanks phuzi, I am going back into code and removing some Task.FromResults. I tried to upcheck your comment but don't have the reputation to do it.

Feel free to upvote the answer too

Upvoted! Thanks!

I'd go with the readable answer - after all, code that is written in a way that is easily understandable is the most elegant of all :)
private async Task<bool> IsUserSet()
{
    if (user == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return await getUserAsync();
    }
}

Speaking of which, I'd probably comment on the choice of name for getUserAsync(), as it doesn't actually return a user. A better choice of name would make the code a lot more readable.

Pedro-- Yes, I see that you are right, just like Akash commented above. I'm changing it to setUserAsync. Thanks for the example, that sounds right though I am still curious about inserting another async Task, since apparently ReSharper doesn't like it so much.

In a way I would consider the async task there not good design - I guess it breaks SRP because a method in charge of checking if a user is set also tries to create one.

Let's jump to the gist of the question:

However, I'm wondering if the performance hit (there is one with inserting another Task isn't there?) is worth it, or if there is a way to do this without inserting another task. (Or maybe I just need some education on how to write cleaner ASP.NET code!)

The general recommendation is to use Task unless you've come across a performance-critical scenario, where its usage becomes (or might become) a problem. Yes, there is a small overhead with Tasks, but this is .NET, there's some overhead with practically everything. If you're writing a core framework or a library with performance focus, then by all means, do think about these topics, but these projects typically already have some guidelines on where and how performance matters.
To explain a bit further, essentially, Task allocations have two portions:

The Task object itself
The asynchronous state machine that represents the async method in case when await actually causes a suspension

The Task object allocation can be avoided in certain cases. When returning Task synchronously, there is a Task.CompletedTask singleton that can be reused. However, there is also a caching for certain scenarios such as Task<bool> - a synchronously completed Task<bool> can either contain true or false so there are two instances cached by the runtime. As the scenario in question works with Task<bool>, the synchronous path is essentially allocation-free and this is not a concern.
Async state machine gets allocated in case of suspension. That is when the method does not complete synchronously (i.e. because actual I/O is performed such as sending an HTTP request). The runtime needs to store locals and continuation on heap so that it can continue in the same logical context once the asynchronous operation completes. So in this case, allocation is not avoidable.
Some state machine allocations can be eliminated by not using async methods when await is not needed, e.g.
// Before: async
public async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    DoSomething();
    DoSomethingElse();
    await DoSomethingAsync();
}

// After: no async, return task from callee
public Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    DoSomething();
    DoSomethingElse();
    return DoSomethingAsync();
}

However, this has the cost of those methods no longer being present in stack traces, which is not to be underestimated.
There is also a concept of ValueTask and ValueTask<T>. These are structs and so their creation does not allocate. However, they still do allocate a state machine box when async method suspends and it is a bit bigger than the one created for Task. There is a case where this can also be avoided with ValueTask which is using IValueTaskSource to pool the async state storage. This is really complex and does not apply everywhere.
So to sum up:



Primitive
Allocates on synchronous completion
Allocates on suspension




Task
No (Task.CompletedTask singleton)
Yes


Task<bool>
No (Task.FromResult returns one of two true/false cached instances)
Yes


Task<T>
Yes*
Yes


ValueTask and ValueTask<T>
No
Yes**



*) There are more exceptions such as ints in range [-1, 9), null, default(T) for some value types
**) Unless using IValueTaskSource which is not common in application code
Several years ago, Stephen Toub wrote a blog post that goes into the details of this topic and serves as a fine overview. I can also recommend Stephen Cleary's blog where he explains topics related async/await and more.
But in general, use what you suggested originally and you'll be just fine.
private async Task<bool> IsUserSetAsync()
{
    return user != null || await getUserAsync();
}

or, if you truly must elide the await:
private Task<bool> IsUserSetAsync()
{
    if (user != null)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
    else
    {
        return getUserAsync();
    }
}


Wow I just checked phuzi's response as the answer and then edited my original post to summarize the other comments, then after I saved it all I saw that your reponse was just posted. Thank you, your information is really informative and helps me understand things much better, and includes additional references. I'm really thankful for all the information from everybody about async task processing.
